# Meteor website showing "Bad Gateway" for unknown reasons

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2, mup

We are hosting one of our website on AWS, deployed successfully without any error but sometimes for some unknown reasons it shows **"BAD GATEWAY"**, unable to figure out why it is so. In this case, we manually again deploy it and everything goes to normal, but the thing is we can not afford it as the website is on production and it is hampering our product. Any suggestion why this is happening. Is anyone out there experiencing the same issue? Please help me out with this.

Also, I want to confirm whether it is happening because of the following situations -

```
a) AWS EC-2 instance stop/start/restart
b) Memory issue
```

The result of  **df -h**

```
  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
  tmpfs           396M   41M  355M  11% /run
  /dev/xvda1       30G   24G  5.8G  81% /
  tmpfs           2.0G  1.6M  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
  tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
  tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Update:
We are using nginx as proxy and app is deployed using MUP tool.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing the ssl and using it at nginx level

Answer (score 0):

You can check EC2 server memory/CPU in AWS Cloudwatch https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/ .

But the reason might be also:

- Crashing Meteor website - check your logs.
- Blocked NodeJS event loop - we experienced Bad Gateway errors in our Meteor app during the generation of large XMLs. This was easily solved by moving that functionality into separate process.

Comment: Just checked it there are some in-app consoles and one error regarding meteor method. Meteor method failed because we recently changed our mail-server and email related configuration process.env.MAIL_URL is pointing out to something older one.